# Lightning component afterRender not displaying component's attributes values

Tags: lightning, lightning-renderer

I have an `afterRender` function on the component's renderer that I need to retrieve some information to work with
This is my logic:

```
({
    // Your renderer method overrides go here
    afterRender : function(component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
        var formElements = document.getElementsByClassName("slds-grid"); 
        for(var i=0; i<formElements.length; i++){
            console.log("element: " + formElements[i].innerHTML);
        }
        var dependentFields = component.get("v.dependentFields");
        console.log("dependentFields: " + dependentFields);
    }
})
```

And when opening the console `formElements` displays nothing and when showing the length it displays **0**. Same goes for `dependentFields` (after `init` method on js controller finishes it's full with values but here displays nothing at all).

**What could be the problem? And how can I fix this?**

**EDIT:**

What I need to achieve on this is running through all the elements of the form and hide the ones that its name attribute corresponds with one of the `dependentFields` list.

Comment: Depending on the namespaces involved, LockerService is very likely to get in the way here.

Comment: So there's no way to achieve this? I haven't worked with renderer before... @KeithC

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), from what I can tell. What we really need to is is your *form's* code so we can prescribe the proper solution. afterRender is used to manipulate *your component's DOM*, not for anything else (event other components in your own namespace should be considered off limits). Thanks, and we look forward to your update.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The point is that I'm currently creating lightning:recordForm elements dinamically and what I want to do is on `afterRender` check in the dom if there are elements with `slds-grid` class which sons have name attribute like one of the `dependentFields` list but on afterRender it tells me there are no `slds-grid` elements but there are! So what can I do? @sfdcfox

Comment: @molinet You can't mess with another component's DOM. That's the point of Locker Service. You will have better luck asking about your original problem (the X), rather than trying to subvert Locker Service.

Comment: As you said earlier I wasn't looking in the right direction. Now I've determinated what my problem really is and achieve to solve it so thanks a lot for your help! @sfdcfox